# Keras with ensembles

Tags: scikit-learn, keras, ensemble-learning

I'm building ensemble such as Voting using SKlearn and Stacking using brew. However, I Keras wrapper doesn't work correctly.

Building the Voting classifier I receive when one of the elements if KerasClassifier gives me folowing error:

```
TypeError: cannot create 'sys.flags' instances
```

Building Stacking classifier I'm getting:

```
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'classes_'
```

How could I use Keras with ensembles? Do I have to change framework?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the `KerasClassifier` object with a `CalibratedClassifierCV` object as such:

```
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
model = CalibratedClassifierCV(KerasClassifier(...))
```

Referenced from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54402210/how-to-enable-probability-estimates-when-using-scikitlearns-linearsvc-classifie/54403345#54403345).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but after 2.5 years I do not have access to the code anymore to test it