# how to enable probability estimates when using scikitlearn's LinearSVC classifier

Tags: scikit-learn, probability, svc

How can I get the probability estimates of predictions from a `sklearn.svm.LinearSVC` model in similar fashion to `sklearn.svm.SVC`'s `probability=True` option that allows `predict_proba()` I need to avoid the quadratic fit penalty of the underlying `libsvm` of `SVC` as my training set is large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sklearn.svm.LinearSVC` does not have `predict_proba` method as you noticed correctly.

However, you may try the following trick to circumvent this shortcoming:

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
svm = CalibratedClassifierCV(LinearSVC())
svm
CalibratedClassifierCV(base_estimator=LinearSVC(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=True, fit_intercept=True,
     intercept_scaling=1, loss='squared_hinge', max_iter=1000,
     multi_class='ovr', penalty='l2', random_state=None, tol=0.0001,
     verbose=0),
            cv=3, method='sigmoid')
```

The resulting `svm` model indeed has `predict_proba` method available.

You may read more about [CalibratedClassifierCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV.html)